# Cannot use errno.h with gcc/g++ after updating ubuntu 10.4

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, ubuntu, g++

After updating Ubuntu 10.4, I'm not able to build any projects with errno.h used in them. EPERM, EINVAL,... are now "undeclared"

I tried tracking down the problem, and I think it's some messup with the gcc, or with ubuntu packages, because in /usr/include/linux/errno.h:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_ERRNO_H
#define _LINUX_ERRNO_H

#include <asm/errno.h>


#endif
```

this 3. line is erroneous. Compiler says "Cannot find include file "

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: So, does `/usr/include/asm/errno.h` actually exist?

Comment: How do _you_ `include` `errno.h`? There exist different incarnations of that file. Canonically, you just `#include <errno.h>`.

Comment: @aix Well, no :D. Actually /usr/include/asm directory does not exist at all. There is /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h.

@phresnel
Yeah, I just do #include<errno.h>. But everything worked until last update :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 10.04 system, `/usr/include/asm/errno.h` is part of the `linux-libc-dev` package.

I suggest you perform a clean reinstall of that package.

Comment: This helped :), although I had to reinstall g++ afterwards. Thanks, vote up and I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the corresponding `linux-headers-X` package installed, where X is the version of the kernel you're running (or compiling against).

Comment: I just checked. My kernell running is 2.6.38-10-generic #44Ubuntu, and I have linux-headers-2.6.38-10.44. It seems like something else is the problem :S